# STM32 IAP firmware update

Tags: stm32, flash, firmware, flash-memories

I'm trying to update STM32f105vct6 firmware using [STM32 IAP](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-iap-usart.html) over UART.  I can update firmware if .bin file size smaller than 32 kB, otherwise file transfer stops after sending 32 kB data. When I looked with logic analyzer, MCU sends ack (0x06) until receive 32 kB data then MCU send nack (0x15) after data comes. Flash size of MCU is 256 kB so there is enough space. What can be the reason?